# Why isn't 'Inset with individual origins' working?

Tags: modeling, mesh

What am I doing wrong? When I'm inserting one face at a time it works fine. When I select more the result is the same no matter if I choose individual origins or median point.

[image]

Comment: The link is not working.  Please insert an image or .gif  .

Comment: Currently, I don't understand your question. Can you add more details?

Comment: It's because I've expected the faces automatically to scale to their respective centers just by choosing the origins to local forgot about the "individual" check box under the insert options.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With some faces selected in *Edit Mode* press <kbd>I</kbd> to create insets, the status bar changes and displays that you need to press <kbd>I</kbd> again.

[image]

What you show in the animation is changing the *pivot point* to *individual origins* which does not affect the inset operator.

Answer (score 0):

Found it myself, the "individual" option has to be marked.  I had expected the faces automatically to scale to their respective centers just by choosing the origins to local. Forgot to check the "individual" box under the insert options.

Comment: @Brat you can expand your Q and A to make it useful for others as well as you

Comment: Q and A meaning Question and Answer? You mean more explanation what I did and how?

Comment: yes exactly ( see like stacker's answer)